# If condition satisfies Not to apply any coupon (No coupon)

Tags: magento-1.9, quote, coupon

We have a customization like a **quote edit** and approve functionality.

> **Ex:** Original product price is 350 where customer write a note "I need this product for 200" admin can approve the request at this
>   scenario if the quote has edited and approved I don't want to apply a
>   coupon (No Coupon) because already we have reduced the product price.

Can any one suggest me the best way to fix this?